# React Native Node install Error

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native

I am trying to install the environment for react native.
I followed the instruction of the site until the point to enter into the cmd

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject
```

after several moments I get a big green message:

```
You are currently running Node v0.12.2.                                  

   React Native runs on Node 4.0 or newer. There are several ways to         
   upgrade Node.js depending on your preference.                             

   nvm:       nvm install node && nvm alias default node                     
   Homebrew:  brew unlink iojs; brew install node                            
   Installer: download the Mac .pkg from https://nodejs.org/                 

   About Node.js:   https://nodejs.org                                       
   Follow along at: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2545
```

I try to upgrade my nodejs but I have the newest version form the site.
why does it still throws me this error ?

Comment: Are you using linux ?

Comment: I am using win 10 pro

Answer (score 5):

Hi user24136 i build react native apps myself and i have latest Node version running. Error states your Node.js installed is old and React Native does run on Node 4.0+. Seems like your on a Mac, visit this link [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download) and use installer to upgrade your NPM and Node to latest versions. After successful installations run commands `node -v` and `npm -v` and you should see newer version `v6.10.3` and `3.10.10` respectively. Then run command `react-native init AwesomeProject` and check if it works.

Comment: I am using win 10 pro. I have visited nodejs.org to try and upgade my version. I have even uninstall my node and install it again just in case and still after checking the version I get the same result

Comment: Do node -v and npm -v and tell us your node, npm versions.

Comment: node version as show in the question v0.12.2
npm version is 4.3.0

Comment: Use these links and run the setup from administrator. For 32 bit windows use https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.3/node-v6.10.3-x86.msi and for 64 bit use https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.10.3/node-v6.10.3-x64.msi. To check your windows architecture press windows button and search System information. If you receive any errors please attach the stacktrace. If the setup is successful you should see v6.10.3 on running command node -v.

Comment: @user24136 Sounds good. Please accept the answer, hopefully it helps someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

This problem interested in from your only node version

you can use

### sudo n stable

command your terminal. This command increase your node version.